# Remove lines from hosts file with batch if already exists

Tags: batch-file, scripting, hosts

I have a batch script to add new entries based on the given IP address:

```
@echo off

SET NEWLINE=^& echo.

set /p ipAddress=What is the IPv4 address of the instance? 

FIND /C /I "storage.app.lab" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%^%ipAddress%    storage.app.lab>>%WINDIR%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

FIND /C /I "home.app.lab" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%^%ipAddress%    home.app.lab>>%WINDIR%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

FIND /C /I "api.app.lab" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%^%ipAddress%    api.app.lab>>%WINDIR%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

pause
```

However, I want to be able to overwrite existing entries with the domain name if a new ip address is entered. For example, if an entry with the domain name of "storage.app.lab" already exists, replace it with the new IP address.

How can I achieve that without using a backup hosts file?

Comment: I would not recommend `cmd` for this. It is doable but I would consider powershell instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q64587777.txt"

:: I'll just use a fixed string for the IPaddress
set "IPaddress=User-input IP address"

:: remove variables starting #
FOR  /F "delims==" %%a In ('set # 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%a="

FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a IN (
 'findstr /v /N /L /C:"storage.app.lab" /C:"home.app.lab" /C:"api.app.lab" "%filename1%"'
 ) DO set "#%%a=%%b"

(
FOR  /F "tokens=1*delims==" %%a In ('set # 2^>Nul') DO echo %%b
for %%a in ("storage.app.lab" "home.app.lab" "api.app.lab") do echo %IPaddress%   %%~a
)>"%filename1%"

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances. The listing uses a setting that suits my system.

I used a file named `q64587777.txt` containing some dummy data for my testing.

The first few lines simply establish filename variables for testing, and a recognisable string to save re-entering data in testing.

The procedure will use variables named `#*` for temporary storage of the "other" lines in the file in question, so first clear out any variables that may exist that start `#`.

Then execute `findstr` and "print" lines that do **NOT** contain (`/V`) any of the `/L` literal strings provided as `/c:"string-to-EXclude"` and `/N` number thos lines with a leading serial number followed by a colon.

The `for /f` tokenises the line using the `:` separator as a delimiter and assigning the line number to `%%a` (token 1) and the remainder of the line (the data in question) to `%%b`. Set the environment variable `#%%a` to the lines found.

Then use the same principle on a `set #` list, which will list all variables starting `#` in the format `#1=line one`, delimiting on `=` and selecting the 2nd token, which is the line data originally read from the file.

And add the three new lines by construction.

Parenthesising the two `for` statements together gathers the `echo`ed output which is then redirected to the original file, overwriting it.

Note that OP's code appended the (up to) three new lines. The requirement is (apparently) that the 3 lines will appear in the file, replacing any existing data for those three entries.